# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError rspec on request post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a UserCourseRegistration table that belongs to the User and Course table, and the User and Course table are has_many through the UserCourseRegistration table. My UserCourseRegistration controller looks like this:

```
class UserCourseRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invite, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @invite = UserCourseRegistration.new
  end

  def create
    @invite = UserCourseRegistration.new(invite_params)
    if @invite.save
      redirect_to '/user_course_registrations'
    else
      render :new, notice: @invite.errors 
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @invite.update(invite_params)
      redirect_to @invite
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @invite.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: true }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_invite
      @invite = UserCourseRegistration.find(params[:id])
    end

    def invite_params
      params.require(:user_course_registration).permit(:course_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

When I try to do a controller test in rspec for the create method the following message is given:

> Failure/Error: post :create, params: { user_course_registration:
>   @user_course_attributes }
>
> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
>   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

My test was:

```
before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @current_user_admin = create(:admin)
    @current_user = create(:user)
    sign_in @current_user_admin
  end
describe "POST #create" do
    context 'user is admin' do
      before(:each) do
        @school = create(:school, user: @current_user_admin)
        @course = create(:course, user: @current_user_admin, school: @school)
        @user_course_attributes = attributes_for( :user_course_registration, 
                                                  user_id: @current_user_admin.id, 
                                                  course_id: @course.id
                                                  )

          post :create, params: { user_course_registration: @user_course_attributes }
        end

        it 'redirect to show' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
        expect(response).to redirect_to("/user_course_registration")
      end
    end
   end
```

What can it be?

Comment: At what line is the error occuring (in the backtrace) ? And what is returned by the method attributes_for ?

Comment: {:user_id=>3518, :course_id=>1206} this is returned by attributes_for in variable @user_course_attributes

Comment: the line is: rspec ./spec/controllers/user_course_registrations_controller_spec.rb:133 # UserCourseRegistrationsController POST #create user is admin redirect to show and it happens after the method POST is called.